# Android deep link - custom host, custom scheme

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have checked all the available material on how to react to custom deep link but no luck.

Reacting to standard deep link is easy, even to react on something like:

```
testapp://www.something.com/payload=12345
```

The manifest scheme for this would look like:

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="testapp"
                    android:host="www.something.com"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
```

And this works fine...

BUT :) , how to react to a deep link in a format like this ?

```
testapp://payload=12345
```

What would be the **host** value in the intent filter in this case ?

Basically to have this text in some mail, text app, whatever...

```
testapp://payload=12345
```

and when you click on it, to open the app ?

Answer (score 0):

The scheme should look like this:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="testapp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This is working.